# How do you install Libevent for PHP?

Tags: php, debian, libevent

I installed the `libevent-dev` library on my Debian 7 64bit desktop:

```
$ sudo aptitude install -y libevent-dev
```

Then I installed the PECL library

```
$ pecl list
Installed packages, channel pecl.php.net:
=========================================
Package  Version State
libevent 0.1.0   beta
```

I've restarted PHP and the OS but PHP doesn't list libevent as an installed ext in with `phpinfo()` and I get `"PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function event_base_new()"` when I try to use it.

How do you install Libevent?

Comment: A [related question](http://serverfault.com/questions/271554/problems-installing-php-libevent-pecl-package) which the solution didn't work.

Answer (score 9):

**Install Libevent for PHP 5.X**

```
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
sudo pecl install libevent-beta

sudo su
sudo echo 'extension=libevent.so' > /etc/php5/mods-available/libevent.ini
exit

sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/libevent.ini /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d/
sudo ln -s /etc/php5/mods-available/libevent.ini /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/

sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

**Install Libevent for PHP 7.X**

At this time pecl package libevent is not available for php 7

https://pecl.php.net/package/libevent

So let's compile it.

Download master:
https://github.com/expressif/pecl-event-libevent

Unpack to: /tmp/install_libevent

```
cd /tmp/install_libevent/pecl-event-libevent-master
sudo phpize
sudo ./configure
```

After this step scroll our console window and try find any Warnings or Errors. I got one warning - required to install re2c package.

```
sudo make
sudo make install

sudo su
sudo echo 'extension=libevent.so' > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/libevent.ini
exit

sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/libevent.ini /etc/php/7.0/fpm/conf.d/20-libevent.ini
sudo ln -s /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/libevent.ini /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-libevent.ini

sudo service php7.0-fpm restart
```

Answer (score 2):

I've successfully installed it.
These are the steps:

```
apt-get install libevent-dev 
sudo pecl install libevent
```

Edit: Press enter when you are asked for the libevent installation directory (autodetect)

; Add `extension=libevent.so` in the *.ini file where you desire to load it. For example if you want this extension to be loaded always, create a libevent.ini file where your php5 mods are (in my computer they are in `/etc/php5/mods-available/`) and write `extension=libevent.so`. Enable this module then with `php5enmod libevent`. This [page](http://www.lornajane.net/posts/2012/managing-php-5-4-extensions-on-ubuntu) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add `extension=libevent.so` to php.ini.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Edited my answer. I intended to add the clarification as a comment. Since I do not have enough reputation, I had no other go but to post it as an answer.